# Adding loading configuration into inject dependencies in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In my Asp.Net Core API, I have some repository classes I'm injecting by using the services.AddTransient method in my Startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<IRepository, Repository>();
```

I'm also loading a section of my appsettings.json into a custom object in the Startup.cs

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

My repository class needs to load the db connection string from the appsettings.json. Is there a way to inject these settings straight to the repository class? Or is it up to the constructor of the controller to pass the connection string to the repository class?

Comment: You can inject the config into your controller, then, pass it to your repository class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can inject this directly to your repository.

```
    public MyRepository(IOptions<MyConfig> config)
    {
        var connString = config.Value.DbConnString;
    }
```

where MyConfig is a POCO object of your configuration and is getting added/registered in startup:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.Configure<MyConfig>(Configuration);
    }
```

The MyConfig can look something like this:

```
    public class MyConfig
    {
        public string DbConnString { get; set; }
    }
```

And the appsettings.json like this:

```
{
  "ApplicationName": "MyApp",
  "Version": "1.0.0",
  "DbConnString ": "my-conn-string"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I just misunderstood that the configuration wouldn't just apply to the controllers.