# Access config.json in Controller

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to access values in my **config.json** file, but it is returning null values in my controllers and when testing in **Startup.cs**.

**In Startup.cs**

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();      
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  /*...

  ...*/
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftAzureStorage"));
```

**In the Controller**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private string _token;

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public TestController(IOptions<AppSettings>settings)
    {
        _token = settings.Value.token; //returns Null
    }
```

**AppSettings.cs**

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

}
```

**Config.json**

```
{
    "MicrosoftAzureStorage": 
    {
        "AzureStorageConnectionString": "RandomConnectionString"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding JsonFiles without knowing that they are really present.

```
.AddJsonFile("config.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
```

If you change optional: true to false then you'll probably get an exception. Since I am missing one piece of information, publishOptions in Project.json I cannot be sure. Check publishOptions, you may have to add appsettings.json:

```
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: There is no publishOptions in Config.json, I added it, but there was no difference, I also tried adding it to the publishOptions in Project.json

Comment: My mistake, Project.json not config.json. I've updated that in the answer. It seems that the problem is somewhere else. to make sure, what happens if you change optional to false?

Comment: If I change both .addJsonFile to optional:false for config.json I get a FileNotFound

Comment: There is only one, and one is enough. So you can change it back to true.

Comment: I solved it , I added the config.json to publishOptions and had to change the ApplicationName variable in AppSettings.cs to "AzureStorageConnectionString" to match the value I am looking for in config.json. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The property name has to match the key name in the json file. See similar example here: [Adding loading configuration into inject dependencies in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40770093/adding-loading-configuration-into-inject-dependencies-in-asp-net-core/40772930#40772930)

Answer (score 0):

Snippet of code I have been using in my application.

In startup.cs

```
 public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddJsonFile("secondary.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

In controller method or helper class.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.AddJsonFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/secondary.json");
var configuration = builder.Build();
var myValue = configuration["MicrosoftAzureStorage:AzureStorageConnectionString"];
```